# Azure DevOps Pipeline Pass Object Array to ARM Template

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I am new to Azure devOps pipelines.

I have a graphical 'build' pipeline where there is a step that calls a .json ARM template located in source control.

I have a parameter called 'tags'. I need to pass in an 'object array' - the array just contains strings.

```
 "parameters": {
        "rgName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "rgLocation": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "tags": {
            "type": "object",
            "defaultValue": {}
        }
    },
```

In the pipelines step I set the 'Override template parameters' however I am setting the value for the -tags parameter incorrectly - "eployment template validation failed: 'Template parameter 'tags' was provided an invalid value. Expected a value of type 'Object', but received a value of type 'String'." - how do I correct this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am able to reproduce your issue.

[image]

The below Template and YAML file should be able to achieve your requirements:

**xxx.yml**

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'
variables:
  tags: '{"xxx":["value1", "value2", "value3"]}'
steps:
- task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
  displayName: 'ARM Template deployment: Resource Group scope'
  inputs:
    azureResourceManagerConnection: 'xxx'
    subscriptionId: 'xxx'
    resourceGroupName: 'xxx'
    location: 'xxx'
    csmFile: Template.json
    overrideParameters: '-rgname ''xxx'' -rglocation ''xxx'' -tags $(tags)'
```

**Template.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    
    "rgName": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1
    },
    "rgLocation": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1
    },
    "tags": {
      "type": "object",
      "defaultValue": {}
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "testVNETPrefix": "10.0.0.0/16",
    "testVNETSubnet1Name": "Subnet-1",
    "testVNETSubnet1Prefix": "10.0.0.0/24",
    "testVNETSubnet2Name": "Subnet-2",
    "testVNETSubnet2Prefix": "10.0.1.0/24"},
  "resources": [
    {
      "name": "testVNET3",
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "apiVersion": "2016-03-30",
      "dependsOn": [ ],
      "tags": {
        "displayName": "testVNET"
      },
      "properties": {
        "addressSpace": {
          "addressPrefixes": [
            "[variables('testVNETPrefix')]"
          ]
        },
        "subnets": [
          {
            "name": "[variables('testVNETSubnet1Name')]",
            "properties": {
              "addressPrefix": "[variables('testVNETSubnet1Prefix')]"
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "[variables('testVNETSubnet2Name')]",
            "properties": {
              "addressPrefix": "[variables('testVNETSubnet2Prefix')]"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }],
  "outputs": {}
}
```

Success:

[image]

Comment: You are not using the 'tags' parameter in the JSON. Not sure if this was on purpose, but you didn't provide a working solution.